# How to read values from 'WPF' project App.config file from within class library

Tags: app-config

I have a WpfApplication project (Visual Studio 2008) with an app.config generated from entering 'Name' and 'Value' pairs in the Settings.settings file (and therefore generating 'applicationSettings' elements rather than 'appSettings' elements).

I have added a class1 class library project in the same Visual Studio solution.

** I have added the WpfApplication app.config file to the class1 project using "add existing item and then add as link".** since found out this is unneccassary (i.e. string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("key1"); below works without this)

**I want to read the values within app.config from class1** and have explored the following:

```
string s1 = Settings.Default.appsetting1;
```

But I do not want to reference the WpfApplication10 project from Class 1 project and so cannot get a reference to the Settings class. So this syntax only works within the WPF project.

```
string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("key1").ToString();
```

This does work, but only if I add the following to app.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="key1" value="1"/>
</appSettings>
```

Are there other ways to achieve what I want which may be better (e.g. offering type safety or being able to read the Settings class properties?

Comment: Ran into this while doing the same research. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400097/reading-from-app-config-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following thing:
if you need to get value from key="key1" just write this(supposing your app.config is in the correct directory).

```
string str=System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["key1"];
```