# Mono not reading values from my app.config?

Tags: c#, mono, app-config

I have a standard `app.config` for a .NET 4.0 Console application created by Visual Studio 2010 when adding settings in the project Settings tab as described on MSDN here: [Application Settiings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

If I update a setting value in the resulting `MyAsseblyName.exe.config` file in the same directory then run the exe I see this in code by going:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;
```

However, if I do the same (with the same build and same files) running Mono 3.2.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 using the above line gives me the default value specified on project Settings tab instead of the updated value in the `MyAsseblyName.exe.config` file.

What do I have to do to make mono use my app.config like .NET does so values are read from file if they are there?

**Workaround**

For anyone else coming across this issue I was able to workaround it by moving my settings in my app.config into the old-school `<appSettings>` element from `<userSettings>` or `<applicationSettings>` created by the project designer. Then you can use:

```
var myValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There is a Mono bug report [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15818), which may be related to your issue. There is also a related [pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/964). I had originally written this as an answer but after looking at the code in the pull request, I am not totally sure if it solves your problem. In other words it requires further investigation, and I don't have the time to do so.

Comment: The workaround does not work for me. Also, is the supposed to be called app.config or App.config?