# Reading xml tags file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ConnectionParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <configuration>
  <loginId1>id 1</loginId>
  <loginPass1>passwd 1</loginPass1>
  <loginId2>id 2</username>
  <loginPass2>passwd 2</loginPass2>
 </configuration>
</ConnectionParams>
```

I have to get the value of each loginPass from a c# program. Can you suggest how to do this. I have just started working with c#.

Thanks.

Comment: Read aboud the System.XML namespace, speciffically about the XMLDocument class.

Comment: If this is your App.config / Web.config file check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400097/reading-from-app-config-file instead of manually parsing with System.XML

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**linq to xml**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview).

```
var loginpass = from l in xdoc.Descendants("configuration")
                 select new { 
                   loginPass1 = l.Attribute("loginPass1").Value                   
                };
```